# Perl - Login to mutiple servers and grep for an error in logs

Tags: perl

I'm Trying to login to multiple servers and grep for a specific error in the logs. If the error is found then output the hostname of the server and how many times the error occurred

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

my $uid = $ENV{'LOGNAME'};
my $server;
my @hosts = ('server1','server2','server3','server4','server5','server6','server7','server8');
print "Log Date (MM-DD): ";
my $LD8 = <STDIN>;
print "host             Error Occured \n";
print "--------------  ---------------\n";
for each $server (@hosts) {
    open my $tc, 'ssh -q $uid@$server "grep -c 'Error Occured' /home/perry/error.log-$LD8"', or die "could not run";
    while (<$tc>) {
        print "$server      '$_'\n";
    } #--while
} #--for
close $tc;
```

Comment: So what's your specific question?

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. was looking for recommendation/better ways of doing this

Comment: Cool - maybe edit the post so it's asking that question (it's just a statement now), and if possible show where its's going wrong or what the output is.

Comment: For starters, single quote strings do not do variable interpolation, so that's a major problem.  Fix that and see what happens, there are probably other issues.

Comment: There are various issues with your code. I think you've not put your real code into your question. We can't help you if you don't show what you are really running. Please [edit] your question and show us your actual code. Also include `use strict` and make sure it compiles. For example, the `for each $server (@hosts) { ... }` will fail because `each` is an unknown function. That keyword is `foreach` without a space. Your string quoting is also completely messed up and will lead to compilation errors.

Comment: Have a look at [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) and [`Net::OpenSSH::Parallel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel).

Comment: i would use expect (https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) to log in and run the commands and then log out. yes there are newer and better ways (maybe) but expect once you've done it once is easy

Comment: there sholuldn't be a `,` before `or die`  too

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```perl
open my $tc, 'ssh -q $uid@$server "grep -c 'Error Occured' /home/perry/error.log-$LD8"'
```

Is problematic for a number of reasons.  You probably want the variable names `$uid`, `$server` and `$LD8` to be replaced with the contents of those variables.  But the string uses single quotes - which is what you use when you *don't* want variables to be interpolated.  Also, the string contains single quotes, so it's probably triggering a syntax error.

To make it more challenging, your string also contains double quote characters.  You could backslash-escape them like this:

```perl
open my $tc, "ssh -q $uid@$server \"grep -c 'Error Occured' /home/perry/error.log-$LD8\""
```

Or you could use the `qq()` operator as alternative double quote delimiters.

```perl
open my $tc, qq(ssh -q $uid@$server "grep -c 'Error Occured' /home/perry/error.log-$LD8")
```

But there's still a problem because that string is a command but you're passing it to `open` as if it was a filename so it's still not going to work.  If you want `open` to treat the argument as a command and run it, with its STDOUT attached to a pipe, so that you can read from the pipe to get the command's output, then you need to add a pipe character (`|`) as the last character in the string:

```perl
open my $tc, qq(ssh -q $uid@$server "grep -c 'Error Occured' /home/perry/error.log-$LD8" |)
```